# Not able to start Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have followed the instructions from:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR5/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html

With no success, not sure what can be missing.

I have some code demo at: https://github.com/dbranco/eureka-server

I was expecting to run: gradlew bootRun and be able to navigate into http://localhost:8761, but I am getting a

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Jul 09 00:13:18 BST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

And when starting the server I am getting some connection refused. Can someone pinpoint what is missing?

I have tried the post from here without success:
[I got a "Whitelabel Error Page" when using Eureka server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577161/i-got-a-whitelabel-error-page-when-using-eureka-server)

Comment: Make sure you enabled eureka server using `@EnableEurekaServer`, inside the Main class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eureka server itself has no web pages except the dashboard page. Since your server starts successfully, I guess your problem is, why you can't access the dashboard page. Also after looking at your Github `application.properties` file, I would suggest below configs,

```
spring.application.name=demo-eureka-server
server.port=8761

eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.dashboard.path=/dashboard
```

After these configurations, you should able to access the dashboard via **`http://localhost:8761/dashboard`** url. Also, if your client services have configured correctly, you should see each of the connecting service in this dashboard.

**EDIT**

Although, `eureka.dashboard.path=/dashboard` and `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost` would not be mandatory, **`eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false`** is required. This property avoid `Eureka` server to register with itself as a client and make it act as a server. This `eureka.client.fetch-registry=false` property also required, if there are no other registry nodes available at the moment. It tells, `Eureka` server to don't search for other registry nodes.

And, yes. If the `eureka.dashboard.path=/dashboard` not defined, dashboard would available at the root (`http://localhost:8761/`).

Comment: Hello Sachith,

Not sure about this, your answer worked, but if I only use the first two lines also works except that the dashboard is in the root path instead the /dashboard.

The only difference is that I have generate the project again with the start.spring.io and generating a jar instead a war.

Regards.

Comment: it is good to write pom.xml for other people may don't know , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try including bootstrap dependency on service project if you are running config server on different port and renamed service project's properties file to `bootstrap.properties`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Spring Cloud Version and Spring Version is supposed to work together, for newer versions there is a incompatibility warning implemented, this was not the case for older versions. You can check the compatible versions here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud